# Cannot see my code on the debug windows

Tags: eclipse

Hi I used the Eclipse for creating a project. I don't know what I did that make my code didn't show on the debug windows. How to solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the console log window is on top of the editor. Resize it to be shorter.

You could also just reset your perspective to the default layout. Use `Window > Reset Perspective...` menu item.